# Where is the right place to add Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm very new to flutter. I've been following certain courses, but coming to firebase, methods and properties have changed a lot and  I'm facing some difficulty in figuring out how to connect to firebase.
Here I have added my `main.dart` file.

```
import 'package:flash_chat/screens/cart_screen.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/screens/stationery.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/screens/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/screens/registration_screen.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/screens/chat_screen.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/screens/buyer_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() => runApp(FlashChat());

class FlashChat extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: WelcomeScreen.id,
      routes: {
        WelcomeScreen.id: (context) => WelcomeScreen(),
        LoginScreen.id: (context) => LoginScreen(),
        RegistrationScreen.id: (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
        ChatScreen.id: (context) => ChatScreen(),
        BuyerScreen.id: (context) => BuyerScreen(),
        StationeryScreen.id: (context) => StationeryScreen(),
        CartScreen.id: (context) => CartScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Do I need to add that in main.dart itself or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, firebase plugin methods are changed, now you have to initialize the firebase before you use them, I initialize the firebase method in main.dart file inside the main function like this.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(FlashChat());
}
```